# NSView receiving click events thru a NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nstextview, mouseclick-event

I have a NSTextView, non-editable, non-selectable, in a NSView. I need the NSView to receive click events when the text view is clicked - basically I need the click events to act as though the text view doesn't even exist. Obviously I would just use the

```
textView:clickedOnCell:inRect:atIndex:
```

text view delegate method, but I need to capture the click event, to detect double-clicks and things like that.

Comment: Moreover, that delegate method is only for clicks on attachments (inline images and sounds); it won't fire for clicks on text or the background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the view that contains the text view, override [the `hitTest:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/index.html#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/hitTest%3a) to return `self`. The mouse events will then be sent to the container view.

#### Caveat

I've since found that `hitTest:` will be called for click and mouse-tracking events *anywhere* in the window, even for events that wouldn't naturally be anywhere near the container view. If there are other views in the window, your `hitTest:` method will turn the container view into a black hole that causes all of those events to gravitate into itself, never to be seen by any other views.

The fix for that is to test whether the event is within your view before swallowing it. If it is, return `self`; if it isn't, return `nil`.

The simplest way to do that is to call `super`'s implementation, which will return the view or any subview of itself if the point is within the view, and then just return `self` if that method returned non-`nil`. If it returned `nil`, then you return `nil`, too.

A less-simple but possibly more efficient method would be to [convert the point](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/convertPoint%3afromView%3a) from the window's coordinate system to the view's, then use `NSPointInRect` to test whether the point is within the view's `bounds`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to put Peter's fantastic description into code:

```
- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
    NSView *result = [super hitTest:aPoint];
    if (result)
    {
        result = self;
    }
    return result;
}
```